# Error: An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, crystal-reports

I want to pass three query string variables, which ars DateFrom, DateTo and UserName. When I call that the variable, it shows an error:

> 'An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'admin'.'".

How can I resolve the issue? Here is my code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        strDate = Convert.ToDateTime(Request.QueryString["DateFrom"]);
        endDate = Convert.ToDateTime(Request.QueryString["DateTo"]);
        UserName = Convert.ToSingle(Request.QueryString["UsName"]);
        string UserName = Request.QueryString["UsrName"];
        string sql;
        sql = ("SELECT * FROM tblReport WHERE Date between'" + strDate + "'and'" + endDate + "'and'" + UserName + "'");
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, con);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataSet dst = new DataSet();
        sda.Fill(dst, "tblReport");
        crypt.Load(@"D:\My Project\Asp.Net\ITApplication\ITApplication\CrystalReport.rpt");
        crypt.SetDataSource(dst);
        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = crypt;
 }
```

Comment: Seems you're executing wrong query string. It should be `"SELECT * FROM tblReport WHERE Date between ('" + strDate + "' and '" + endDate + "') and UserName = '" + UserName + "'"` (use parameterized query instead).

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL string is not formatted well.

Put spaces near yout `and` operators and use `()` in your `between`:

```
sql = ("SELECT * FROM tblReport WHERE [Date] between ('" + strDate + "' and '" + endDate + "') and UserName='" + UserName + "'");
```

**Side note**:

Using SQL strings with concatenating values like this is a **very** bad idea. It exposes you to SQL Injections, and overall a bad practice. Please consider using [`Command.Parameters`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
SqlCommand Command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tblReport WHERE [Date] between (@strDate and @endDate) and UserName=@UserName");
Command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("strDate", strDate)); 
Command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("endDate", endDate)); 
Command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("UserName", UserName));
```

Answer (score 0):

you are missing something in your where clause... should be like this:

```
WHERE Date BETWEEN '<FromDate>' AND '<ToDate>' 
AND UserName = '<UserName>'
```